# Storm Global Grouping Fault Tolerance

Tags: apache-storm

I have started to use Storm recently but could not find any resources on the net about global grouping option's fault tolerance.

According to my understanding from the documents; while running a topology with a bolt(Bolt A) which is uses global grouping will receive tuples from tasks of Bolt B into the task of Bolt A. As it is using global grouping option, there is only one task of Bolt A in the topology.

The question is as follows: What will happen if we store some historical data of the stream within Bolt A and the worker process dies which contains the task of Bolt A? Meaning that will the data stored in this bolt get lost?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once all the downstream tasks have acked the tuple, it means that they have successfully processed the message and it need not be replayed if there is a shut down. If you are keeping any state in memory, then you should store it in a persistent store. Message should be acked when the state change due to the message has been persisted.